# Execute 3 functions in parallel on 3 workers

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I've got three functions (`qrcalc`, `zcalc`, `pcalc`) with three unique set of inputs which I want to run in parallel. This is my attempt but it doesn't work:

```
function [outall]=parallelfunc(in1,in2,in3)
if parpool('size') == 0 % checking to see if  pool is already open
    A=feature('numCores');
    parpool('local',A);
else
    parpool close
    A=feature('numCores');
    parpool('local',A);
end

spmd
    if labindex==2
        out1=qrcalc(in1);
    elseif labindex==3
        out2=zcalc(in2);
    elseif labindex==4
        out3=pcalc(in3);
    end

    outall=[out1;out2;out3];
end
```

> Error: Error using parallelattempt>(spmd body) (line 20) Error
>   detected on worker 3. An UndefinedFunction error was thrown on the
>   workers for 'out1'.  This may be because the file containing 'out1' is
>   not accessible on the workers.  Specify the required files for this
>   parallel pool using the command: addAttachedFiles(pool, ...).  See the
>   documentation for parpool for more details.
>
> Error in parallelattempt>(spmd) (line 11) spmd
>
> Error in parallelattempt (line 11) spmd

**Are there any suggestions for how this can be done?**

---

Here is a version of the code that does not require the custom functions. Therefore I replaced them with `zeros`, `magic` and `ones`:

```
function [outall]=parallelattempt(in1,in2,in3)

poolobj = gcp;
addAttachedFiles(poolobj,{'zeros.m','ones.m','magic.m'})

spmd
    if labindex==2
        out1=zeros(in1);
    elseif labindex==3
        out2=magic(in2);
    elseif labindex==4
        out3=ones(in3);
    end

    outall=[out1;out2;out3];
end
```

Comment: What exactly *doesn't work*? I see several things that could be problematic here. It would be beneficial to include error messages and/or an explanation what is not working.

Comment: Hi @Matt, I added the error to the main question with a modified function using zeros, magic and ones. And also starting the parallelpool earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an `spmd`-statement, the code inside will be sent to all workers. By the use of `labindex` you only create the variables `outX` on one specific worker. The problem is, that `outall=[out1;out2;out3];` should now be executed on workers where two `outX`-variables are not declared. The direct fix for this error is to declare the variables before the `spmd`-statement (`out1=[]; out2=[]; out3=[];`). But this is not the best solution.

You can use a single variable inside the `spmd`-statement instead of several ones (`outX`), lets call this variable `out`. Now the code executes on each worker and stores its result in `out`, which is a `Composite`-object. Concatenation is not necessary because it is done automatically. Additionally, you can specify with `spmd (3)` at the beginning of the block that only 3 workers should be used. `Composite`-objects can be indexed like cell arrays where the index equals to the number of the worker/lab. Therefore we can concatenate it after the block.

*This is the specific code for that part:*

```
spmd (3)
    if labindex==1
        out = qrcalc(in1);
    elseif labindex==2
        out = zcalc(in2);
    elseif labindex==3
        out = pcalc(in3);
    end
end

outall = [out{1};out{2};out{3}];
```

Note that the creation of the pool will be done automatically, if none exists. You may need to attach the files of your functions before the statement.

---

An even better approach in my opinion is to use **[`parfeval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html)** here. This does exactly what you want to achieve in the first place - it solves your *initial* problem. The `outX` variables get calculated in parallel (non-blocking). With the function `fetchOutputs` you can block execution until the result is calculated. Use it on all the `outX`-variables and concatenate it in the same line.

*Here is the code for that:*

```
out1 = parfeval(@qrcalc,1,in1);
out2 = parfeval(@zcalc,1,in2);
out3 = parfeval(@pcalc,1,in3);

outall = [fetchOutputs(out1);fetchOutputs(out2);fetchOutputs(out3)];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. However I have one question, will all 3 functions run in parallel to each other, or does the fact that there is an 'if' statement mean they will run subsequent to each other?

Comment: @Trippy Yes, they will run in parallel. The if-statement simply alters what part of the code is executed on each worker. BTW: I added another solution that could be a better fit for your *initial* problem of calculating functions in parallel.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks so much :)